# RVM: Permission denied while loading gemset from .rvmrc file in system-wide install

Tags: ruby, rvm, vagrant

I have created a project specific `.rvmrc` file that includes a custom gemset (using the command `rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.2@registration`):

```
# excerpt of .rvmrc...

environment_id="ruby-1.9.2@registration"

if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments" \
  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id" ]]
then
  \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id"

  if [[ -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/hooks/after_use" ]]
  then
    . "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/hooks/after_use"
  fi
else
  # If the environment file has not yet been created, use the RVM CLI to select.
  if ! rvm --create  "$environment_id"
  then
    echo "Failed to create RVM environment '${environment_id}'."
    return 1
  fi
fi
```

This works locally on my Mac, using single-user RVM. We are also using [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) with a system-wide RVM install on our Vagrant box. However, when we `cd` into the project directory and accept the `.rvmrc` file, it results in the following message (yes, there are a lot of duplicate error messages):

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration': Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration': Permission denied
```

Trying to create the gemset manually mentions the same error, but also mentions that it was successful:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318
$ rvm gemset create registration
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration': Permission denied
'registration' gemset created (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@registration).
```

Do I have something configured incorrectly? How can I resolve this issue so I can use a custom gemset from an `.rvmrc` file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the simple Chef recipe I was using was not adding the vagrant user to the `rvm` group. This could be accomplished by doing this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G rvm vagrant
```

But I decided to switch to a more [robust RVM Chef cookbook](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm) which worked perfectly using these recipes:

```
include_recipe "rvm::system"
include_recipe "rvm::vagrant"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `'sudo'` before your `rvm commands`.  `ruby@registration` will be installed system-wide yet should still work on a per-user basis.

Comment: I'm sure that `sudo rvm ...` will work, but that's not the right solution. When I `cd` into a directory, the `.rvmrc` file should load automatically and create the gemset without requiring sudo. There is a bigger issue going on here.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had .rvm installed in my home directory (user install) but had somehow managed to have the directory chowned by root:root.

*ls -al /home/darren*
*drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Oct  18 16:46 .rvm*

`sudo chown darren:rvm .rvm -R`

`sudo useradd darren rvm`